# Accurately taking a snapshot from a video using a command line tool

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screenshot, snapshot

I am looking for a way to take accurate screenshots from a video. Accurate to the milliseconds. I have tried using `ffmpeg` using the following command:

`ffmepg.exe -ss position-in-hours-minutes-milliseconds -i videoPath -y -f image2 \ -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 screenshot-path`

but the result is not accurate. It does not respect the milliseconds. I need a means of taking a screenshot from a video respecting milliseconds.

Thanks.

Comment: Videos don't use milliseconds, they use frames.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the previous response is misunderstanding your comment regarding millisecond accuracy.
If you want an accurate method of extracting the currently displayed frame, **Avidemux** can be installed as a portable version  and is straight forward to use. Just navigate to your desired frame, then File/Save As Image.

If you want to use ffmpeg, the code below should suffice.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.000 -update 1 -frames:v 1 out.bmp
```

You can change the output to most common image formats.

Comment: Thank you, but same issue. Not milliseconds accurate.

Comment: Just to clarify. Is the problem that ffmpeg selects the nearest pts frame. So, if each frame is 40ms in duration (25fps), a 30ms time setting will select frame two, not frame one. You want all time settings from 0ms to 39ms to select frame one ?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's like using a cannon (not *Canon*) to shoot a flea, both [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org/) and [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) show time wih a resolution of 1/100 second, i.e., ten milliseconds, which is not *quite* what you ask for... but one could *interpolate* by noting the points where the lowest decimal place ticks over, and stretch the timeline so that one could measure along it in ms.

*Caveat:* This is only of use in a video with sufficient *information.* One recorded at any speed less than 100 frames per second does not have any changes on the ms level, and if a video format using [temporal compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/videoencodingwithtemporalcompression) is used, only the *difference* between frames is recorded, making it very difficult, if not impossible, to extract information at the level of a single "frame", i.e., *delta* between full frames.

If you have a true high speed camera with a stand-alone video recorder [**not** using compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncompressed_video), then you can see whole frames in less than ms resolution... and likely have the specialized software to do so.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for automation that is why I asked for a command line tool. Regards.